# Is it possible to assign dynamic loss weighting to losses in a multi-output model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, weighted, loss

I am training a multi-output network for a classification task (one output node for the classification of categories and 2nd output node for the classification of sub-categories).

```
loss_list = {'category': 'categorical_crossentropy',
               'sub_category': 'categorical_crossentropy'}

loss_weights = {'category': 1.0,
                  'sub_category': 0.025}
```

Instead of fixed `loss_weights`, is it possible to adaptively assign `loss_weights` based on the prediction of output1? For example, higher weights for wrong predictions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tensorflow, there is a way to assign class weights while training, but that works only when you have only one output node. So, you will need to convert your multi-output classification model to a single-output classification model. You can achieve this by concatenating your categories and sub-categories.

Let's assume you are classifying the type of a car and the color of a car. Instead of having two labels,

```
("Bugatti", "Orange")
("BMW", "Blue")
("Mercedes", "Black")
("Bugatti", "Orange")
```

You can concatenate them so that it becomes a single label,

```
("Bugatti/Orange")
("BMW/Blue")
("Mercedes/Black")
("Bugatti/Orange")
```

And then apply integer-encoding,

```
(0)
(1)
(2)
(0)
```

Now, create a dictionary containing the class weights. The dictionary should have the format `{CLASS : WEIGHT}`, where `CLASS` is the integer-encoded label and `WEIGHT` is the factor by which the loss value for that particular class will be multiplied. Like this:

```
class_weights = {0: 0.52,
                 1: 0.65,
                 2: 0.30}
```

Now you can mention the parameter `class_weight` while training using `model.fit`.

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, class_weight=class_weights)
```

For more info about this `class_weight` parameter, you can read [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data)

Comment: My question is rather how to apply weights to the two loss functions based on the classification performance of output1 such that output2 gets feedback from output1.

Comment: @DushiFdz Can you model that as a mathematical expression? If so, can you update your question to include that?